# Redirecting to different url and passing some data to it? Dedicated architecture problem

Tags: authentication, redirect, architecture, jwt, iot

This question is going to be a bit complicated. Suppose I have this kind of architecture:

[image: Architecture overview]

Now lets assume that my front end is a react-app and backend is Java Spring server or something less complicated like Python Flask.

I would like to have Auth-FE and BE to be my common authentication GUI and backend due to reason that I might have multiple apps in future (not just AP1) but also maybe other aps like AP2, AP3... AP10 etc. It would be a nightmare for me to have to modify FE Login GUI for each one of those every time I would want to change it. There is also another reason that this whole architecture will be deployed once on localhost with its own WiFi but ALSO on multiple instances of hardware (WiFi + computer) so each DB on every hardware will have different credentials for different users) but there will be some common web interface client (also deployed on each hardware unit) which will make connection with instances of AP1, AP2 (and so on) deployed on the internet for redundancy.

Basically I have multiple robotic unit hardware which need to be operated either locally if no internet connection is available or remotely if there is internet connection available at the moment to the robotic unit.

Now what I intend to do when users opens AP1 in browser is to have AP1 to check if user has JWT in local storage and then proceed as follows if no JWT is present:

1. Redirect to Auth Front-end url and pass parameters in url about the origin from which user came from
2. After user enters credentials, send login request to auth back-end which checks with DB and creates short life-time JWT upon success
3. Auth back-end sends JWT to Auth front-end.
4. Auth front-end receives JWT and redirects user back to AP1 front end passing short-life JWT in url
5. AP1 asks AP1 back-end to check if JWT is valid (why not Auth back-end? Because it might not be available if AP1 front end is instantiated not on localhost but on the web, AP1 back-end will be available on the web however)
6. AP1 back-end sends request with short life JWT to Auth back-end
7. Auth back-end validates and responds with long-life JWT
8. AP1 back-end sends response to AP1 Front-end with long life JWT as response payload or header which AP1 front-end stores in browser local storage and considers user logged in. From here on after every request sent to AP1 back-end protected routes will have this JWT in headers attached which it can can use to authorize endpoints entry.

**Now the QUESTION IS:**
Is it possible to pass the data during redirect to AP1 front-end (step 4) without passing it in URL (is there any other way)?

My reason to do this is to avoid potential cyber-attack vector when user has installed malware plugin that can read urls and send data to web which would allow the attacker to posses JWT string which would allow him to authenticate on any other AP1 (on any other robotic unit) front-end by just typing the correct token in URL.

If it would be possible to send data during redirect in other way than url string, I might not need to ask Auth back-end for extra validation of short-life JWT and provision of long-life JWT because initial JWT (that AP1 front-end would receive in step 4) would be just made as long-life token and considered "good enough" (i.e. not exposed in url).

Of course I would still need to validate that token in local-storage every time user opens the AP1 but this would be going through standard request/response ping-pong as header payload.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an audience claim to your JWT Token that scopes it to a certain AP1.  You can't modify the JWT without corrupting the signature.  If AP1 isn't trusted, you can use asymmetric (private/public) key signing so that AP1 can't change it either.

Comment: Its actually clever but is it any different from defining auth back-end secret key list which it uses to sign token, based on from which AP it was originally sent? For example if it was requested from from AP1 it will provide different JWT signature than if original requestor was AP2. Although if the short-life token would be leaked via browser malware, hacker could still use it to enter AP1 for limited time only (short-life token would live for example 1 minute only) and get long-life JWT. But I can blacklist short-JWT on auth back-end once it's verified and long-life token is sent! Voila! :D